# django DateTimeField in form (initial value)

Tags: python, django, forms, datetime

I have little problem with initial value of DateTimeField in Django forms.

I have declaration in forms.py

```
class FaultForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    date_time = forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), required=False)
    ...
```

I have declaration in models.py

```
class Fault(models.Model):
    ...
    # date time
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    ...
```

Problem is with returning appropriate time.
When I add a few objects to my database with initial/default datetime from my forms.py I have exactly the same time for every object.

But when I add objects with datetime from template, I have good datetime for every object which is in database.

I have to tell my function to returning datetime is exactly the same in both of situation, but maybe problem is with generating the form?? We have the same time because we generate form once, or something like this??

I don't know what to do with this, because I would like to use initial value from forms and don't have to do it again in template.

Ony ideas?? Bug?? Other datetime function?? Other way to solve this little problem??

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function `datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` and assigning the `default` as that. So, during runtime, the `now()` will get evaluated and stored as the default. Hence you see the same datetime across all your objects. You need to use the [`auto_now` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) and set it to `True`.

Model -

```
class Fault(models.Model):
    ...
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ...
```

Comment: in this solution I have such error:

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'date_time' cannot be specified for Fault model form as it is a non-editable field

I try to disable this field but it is not working anyway

Comment: If you want the field to be editable, then remove the `auto_now=True` part in the Model form.

Comment: So your answer is useless. You tell me that I need to use auto_now argument to solve my problem but when this argument give me another problem you tell me that I have to remove auto_now?? How can it help me??

Comment: You did not give the specifics in the question. Anyway, `auto_now` will always add the datetime, and would be render the field as uneditable. You have to choose between adding it automatically or using an editable field, for which you are providing an `initial`. Plain & simple, you just have to remove the `auto_now` from the Model field and keep the `initial` in the Form field, like my answer+comment says. And my answer is not "useless" because I also pointed out the "why" your solution is not working.

Comment: I told it because you told add "auto_now" and after testing you told remove "auto_now", so I was in the same place so before your answer.
Anyway I read something about "auto_now" and how to use it and everything is good now after little changes, so I will plus this answer

Answer (score 3):

Django model fields get evaluated at compile time. In your example above the `default` value gets evaluated *once*.

To fix this simple point the `default` argument to a callable:

```
def get_now():
    return datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

class Fault(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=get_now)
```

Comment: Although this may work, one should prefer the built-in `auto_now`.

Comment: Perhaps, but it depends on the situation and in this question there isn't enough information to reliably suggest that.

Comment: Exactly, since there is not enough information, one should always prefer the built-in.

Comment: good solution but not working as I want,
I have the same time for two object added one after another
What exactly do you want to know??

Answer (score 2):

Use below Python method inside FaultForm class to initialize everytime the memory is allocated for the object:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update( initial = { 'date_time': datetime.now() } )
    super( FaultForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
```

[Explicit return in **init**][1]
[1]: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/explicit_return_in_init.html

Comment: You can also just override `initial` after the `super()` call, e.g. `self.initial['date_time'] = datetime.now()`. Seems less awkward to me.